# Root site collection in Javascript

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to get the Root Site collection url when the context is in a child site, in JavaScript or JQuery.

Comment: Would you like to use ECMA script(client object model)??

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following using client object model

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
var owebsite = clientContext.get_site.get_rootWeb();
```

Without client object model you can use the following

```
var siteCollectionPath= _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: i tried this                                                                                                    var siteCollectionPath = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
      alert(siteCollectionPath); it gives error says _spPageContextInfo not defined. i am using a custom master page in a team site.  and tried this    <script type="text/ecmascript">
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
        var owebsite = clientContext.get_site.get_rootWeb();
        alert(owebsite);
    </script>  it gives JS error ...what am i missing

Answer (score 1):

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.web = clientContext.get_site().get_rootWeb();
```

It's working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean root web or root site collection?

This one will get you the root site collection:

_spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl.replace(_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl, _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl == \"/\" ? \"/\": \"\") + \""

From my post: http://www.rdacorp.com/2015/03/alternate-solution-alternate-css-url-sharepoint-2013-online/

Answer (score 0):

you can get the url without the client object model by using available information and string parse it down from there. Not as robust as the Client-Object model but significantly less complicated for simple tasks.

```
window.location.href
```

...gives you the full window url (e.g. "http://sitecollection.com/sites/mysite/Lists/myList/NewForm.aspx?ContentTypeId=0x01006AC2C39AA621424EBAD9C2AC8A54F8B9007B626ABEEB66E34196C46E13E0CA41A2&ContentTypeName=xxxx")

```
L_Menu_BaseUrl
```

Or

```
_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl
```

...(as Jinxed points out) will give you the relative url (e.g. "/sites/mysite")

Answer (score 0):

Below sample script shows how you can retrieve root web. The onQuerySucceedSample function alerts root site title.

```
getRootWeb = function () {
    //Get and load a reference to the root web of the current site collection.
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var site = ctx.get_site();
    this.rootWeb = site.get_rootWeb();

    ctx.load(this.rootWeb);
    //Ask SharePoint to pull data for us
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,this.onQuerySucceed),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
};

//Function executed on success
onQuerySucceed = function () {
    alert(this.rootWeb.get_title());
};

//Function executed on failure
onQueryFailed = function (sender, args) {
    alert('Unable to retrieve data from the SharePoint. Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
};
```